# spark - convert List of tuples to Dataset - scala

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying out examples to create Datasets and the below one works:

```
val lname = List(("Krishna", 32, "GWL"), ("Pankaj", 37, "BIHAR"), ("Sunil", 29, "Bangalre"))
import spark.implicits._
val rddLName = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(lname)
case class Test1(name: String, age: Int, place: String)
val ds1 = lname.toDS()
val ds2 = rddLName.toDS()
val ds3 = spark.createDataset(rddLName).as("Test1")
val ds4 = rddLName.toDF().as("Test1")
```

a) But how to use as[U](implicit : Encoder[u]) to create a Datasets:
I have tried below code, and it gives me the below error. Could you guide me to some reference.

**Error:(41, 62) Unable to find encoder for type Test1. An implicit Encoder[Test1] is needed to store Test1 instances in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._**

```
val rddNew = lname map{case (x,y,z) => Test1(x,y,z)}
val ds5 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(lname).toDF().as[Test]
ds5.show()
```

The below code is not supported.
    val ds5 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rddNew).toDF()

b) ds4.show() gives me header with _1,_2 and _3 like below:

```
+-------+---+--------+
|     _1| _2|      _3|
+-------+---+--------+
|Krishna| 32|     GWL|
| Pankaj| 37|   BIHAR|
|  Sunil| 29|Bangalre|
+-------+---+--------+
```

How to get name, age and place header with schema provided by me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
case class Test1(name: String, age: Int, place: String)
```

Must be a top-level class, you can't declare it inside methods.

> ds4.show() gives me header with _1,_2 and _3 like below

Your list declaration contains Tuple's not objects, there is no clue for Spark how columns should be named.

```
List(("Krishna", 32, "GWL"), ("Pankaj", 37, "BIHAR"), ("Sunil", 29, "Bangalre"))
```

1. Provide column names

```
import spark.implicits._

val lname: Dataset[Test1] = List(("Krishna", 32, "GWL"), ("Pankaj", 37, "BIHAR"), ("Sunil", 29, "Bangalre"))
  .toDF("name", "age", "place")
  .as[Test1]
lname.show()

+-------+---+--------+
|   name|age|   place|
+-------+---+--------+
|Krishna| 32|     GWL|
| Pankaj| 37|   BIHAR|
|  Sunil| 29|Bangalre|
+-------+---+--------+
```

2. Explicitly change the column names

```
val ds5 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(lname).toDF()
      .withColumnRenamed("_1", "name")
      .withColumnRenamed("_2", "age")
      .withColumnRenamed("_3", "place").as[Test1]
    ds5.show()

+-------+---+--------+
|   name|age|   place|
+-------+---+--------+
|Krishna| 32|     GWL|
| Pankaj| 37|   BIHAR|
|  Sunil| 29|Bangalre|
+-------+---+--------+
```